# wso2 is custom adaptive function not able to set claim

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 IS 5.10, for adding custom claim which needs to be added by fetching from db I am using custom adaptive function. But the below code is not working.

```
package org.wso2.custom.auth.functions;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.config.model.graph.js.JsAuthenticatedUser;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.config.model.graph.js.JsAuthenticationContext;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.model.AuthenticatedUser;
import org.wso2.carbon.utils.multitenancy.MultitenantUtils;
import org.wso2.custom.auth.functions.internal.CustomAuthFuncComponent;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.config.model.graph.js.*;

public class SetForceAuthFunctionImpl implements SetForceAuthFunction {

    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(SetForceAuthFunctionImpl.class);
    
    
    @Override
    public JsAuthenticatedUser setForceAuth(JsAuthenticationContext context, boolean forceAuth) {

        AuthenticatedUser lastAuthenticatedUser = context.getContext().getLastAuthenticatedUser();
        
        LOGGER.info("lastAuthenticatedUser****:::::::::::"+lastAuthenticatedUser);
        String userName = lastAuthenticatedUser.getUserName();
        LOGGER.info("userName2****:::::::::::"+userName);
        
        
        String tenantDomain = MultitenantUtils.getTenantDomain(userName);
        String fullyQualifiedUserName=("USERS"+"/"+userName+"@"+tenantDomain);
        Map<org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model.ClaimMapping, String> claims = new HashMap<org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model.ClaimMapping, String>();
        claims.put(org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model.ClaimMapping.build("test123", "test123", null, true), org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join("*******************",",,,"));
        
        AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUserObj = AuthenticatedUser.createLocalAuthenticatedUserFromSubjectIdentifier(MultitenantUtils.getTenantAwareUsername
                (fullyQualifiedUserName));
        authenticatedUserObj.setAuthenticatedSubjectIdentifier(MultitenantUtils.getTenantAwareUsername
                (fullyQualifiedUserName));
        authenticatedUserObj.setUserAttributes(claims);
        authenticatedUserObj.setUserName(MultitenantUtils.getTenantAwareUsername
                (fullyQualifiedUserName));
        
        
        return new JsAuthenticatedUser(authenticatedUserObj);
    }
}
```

---

```
package org.wso2.custom.auth.functions.internal;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Activate;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Deactivate;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.ReferenceCardinality;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.ReferencePolicy;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.JsFunctionRegistry;
import org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.service.RegistryService;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.service.RealmService;
import org.wso2.custom.auth.functions.GenerateHashFunction;
import org.wso2.custom.auth.functions.GenerateHashFunctionImpl;
import org.wso2.custom.auth.functions.GetClaimsForUsernameFunction;
import org.wso2.custom.auth.functions.GetClaimsForUsernameFunctionImpl;
import org.wso2.custom.auth.functions.GetUsernameFromContextFunction;
import org.wso2.custom.auth.functions.GetUsernameFromContextFunctionImpl;
import org.wso2.custom.auth.functions.SetForceAuthFunction;
import org.wso2.custom.auth.functions.SetForceAuthFunctionImpl;

@Component(
        name = "custom.auth.functions.component",
        immediate = true
)
public class CustomAuthFuncComponent {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CustomAuthFuncComponent.class);
    private static JsFunctionRegistry jsFunctionRegistry;

    @Activate
    protected void activate(ComponentContext ctxt) {

        SetForceAuthFunction setForceAuthFunctionImpl = new SetForceAuthFunctionImpl();
        jsFunctionRegistry.register(JsFunctionRegistry.Subsystem.SEQUENCE_HANDLER, "setForceAuth",
                setForceAuthFunctionImpl);

        GetUsernameFromContextFunction getUsernameFromContextFunctionImpl = new GetUsernameFromContextFunctionImpl();
        jsFunctionRegistry.register(JsFunctionRegistry.Subsystem.SEQUENCE_HANDLER, "getUsernameFromContext",
                getUsernameFromContextFunctionImpl);

        GetClaimsForUsernameFunction getClaimsForUsernameFunctionImpl = new GetClaimsForUsernameFunctionImpl();
        jsFunctionRegistry.register(JsFunctionRegistry.Subsystem.SEQUENCE_HANDLER, "getClaimsForUsername",
                getClaimsForUsernameFunctionImpl);

        GenerateHashFunction generateHashFunctionImpl = new GenerateHashFunctionImpl();
        jsFunctionRegistry.register(JsFunctionRegistry.Subsystem.SEQUENCE_HANDLER, "generateHash",
                generateHashFunctionImpl);
    }

    @Deactivate
    protected void deactivate(ComponentContext ctxt) {

        if (jsFunctionRegistry != null) {
            jsFunctionRegistry.deRegister(JsFunctionRegistry.Subsystem.SEQUENCE_HANDLER, "setForceAuth");
            jsFunctionRegistry.deRegister(JsFunctionRegistry.Subsystem.SEQUENCE_HANDLER, "getUsernameFromContext");
            jsFunctionRegistry.deRegister(JsFunctionRegistry.Subsystem.SEQUENCE_HANDLER, "getClaimsForUsername");
            jsFunctionRegistry.deRegister(JsFunctionRegistry.Subsystem.SEQUENCE_HANDLER, "generateHash");
        }
    }

    @Reference(
            name = "user.realmservice.default",
            service = RealmService.class,
            cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY,
            policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC,
            unbind = "unsetRealmService"
    )
    protected void setRealmService(RealmService realmService) {

        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("RealmService is set in the custom conditional authentication user functions bundle");
        }
        CustomAuthFuncHolder.getInstance().setRealmService(realmService);
    }

    protected void unsetRealmService(RealmService realmService) {

        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("RealmService is unset in the custom conditional authentication user functions bundle");
        }
        CustomAuthFuncHolder.getInstance().setRealmService(null);
    }

    @Reference(
            name = "registry.service",
            service = RegistryService.class,
            cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY,
            policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC,
            unbind = "unsetRegistryService"
    )
    protected void setRegistryService(RegistryService registryService) {

        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("RegistryService is set in the custom conditional authentication user functions bundle");
        }
        CustomAuthFuncHolder.getInstance().setRegistryService(registryService);
    }

    protected void unsetRegistryService(RegistryService registryService) {

        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("RegistryService is unset in the custom conditional authentication user functions bundle");
        }
        CustomAuthFuncHolder.getInstance().setRegistryService(null);
    }

    @Reference(
            service = JsFunctionRegistry.class,
            cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY,
            policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC,
            unbind = "unsetJsFunctionRegistry"
    )
    public void setJsFunctionRegistry(JsFunctionRegistry jsFunctionRegistry) {

        this.jsFunctionRegistry = jsFunctionRegistry;
    }

    public void unsetJsFunctionRegistry(JsFunctionRegistry jsFunctionRegistry) {

        this.jsFunctionRegistry = null;
    }
}
```

But when I am using setForceAuth(context, true); in adaptive authentication function to add custom claims its not working but working in custom authenticator.

Adaptive authentication script:

```
function onLoginRequest(context) {
    doLogin(context);
}

function doLogin(context) {
  executeStep(1,{
        onSuccess: function (context) {
        },
        onFail: function(context){
           executeStep(4,{
                onSuccess: function (context) {
                    var subject = context.currentKnownSubject;
                    setForceAuth(context, true);
                    
            },
                onFail: function(context){
                }
            });
             
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also share the adaptive script (in the above issue by updating the description) that you are trying with the details of the previous steps?

Comment: @SomindaGamage I have updated the adaptive script in question itself. Please check once.

Comment: are you trying to update a user claim from the adaptive script once the user is authenticated from step 4?

Comment: @SomindaGamage yeah session based claim. After login if user selects role I am redirecting again to wso2 is for including the role as new claim in refreshed assertion.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that

`setForceAuth(context, true);`

executes the below code block

`return new JsAuthenticatedUser(authenticatedUserObj);`

There is no point in your code (authencation script or the java function) where the newly created JsAuthenticatedUser is set to the context.

What you need to do is to change the script like this

`onSuccess: function (context) { context.currentKnownSubject = setForceAuth(context, true);}`

or

the java function as below
`@Override
public JsAuthenticatedUser setForceAuth(JsAuthenticationContext context, boolean forceAuth) {

```
    AuthenticatedUser lastAuthenticatedUser = context.getContext().getLastAuthenticatedUser();
    
    LOGGER.info("lastAuthenticatedUser****:::::::::::"+lastAuthenticatedUser);
    String userName = lastAuthenticatedUser.getUserName();
    LOGGER.info("userName2****:::::::::::"+userName);
    
    
    String tenantDomain = MultitenantUtils.getTenantDomain(userName);
    String fullyQualifiedUserName=("USERS"+"/"+userName+"@"+tenantDomain);
    Map<org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model.ClaimMapping, String> claims = new HashMap<org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model.ClaimMapping, String>();
    claims.put(org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model.ClaimMapping.build("test123", "test123", null, true), org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join("*******************",",,,"));
    
    AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUserObj = AuthenticatedUser.createLocalAuthenticatedUserFromSubjectIdentifier(MultitenantUtils.getTenantAwareUsername
            (fullyQualifiedUserName));
    authenticatedUserObj.setAuthenticatedSubjectIdentifier(MultitenantUtils.getTenantAwareUsername
            (fullyQualifiedUserName));
    authenticatedUserObj.setUserAttributes(claims);
    authenticatedUserObj.setUserName(MultitenantUtils.getTenantAwareUsername
            (fullyQualifiedUserName));
    
    
    context.getContext().setSubject(authenticatedUserObj);
}
```

Still it is not advisable to have a tenant aware user name on authentication scripts. Rather can you think of not using

> setForceAuth()

function and use the provided `user.localClaims[]` instead?